# Comparing two strings, they are always equal no matter what?

Tags: python, string

I am just simply trying to compare 3 characters two are given and second is retrieved from variable *a*

Any ideas?

```
a=":-O"
print a[2]
if a[2]== ")" or "D":
    print "Same"
else:
     print "Not same"
```

Comment: This is a common pitfall:
 [chaining of or operator](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/3553/common-pitfalls/14183/chaining-of-or-operator)

Comment: `if a[2] in ')D': ...` :)